# Does Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter persist changes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I realise this is a pretty dumb question, and I have googled.

Does Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter persist changes made in the Weblayer to the DB when the form is submitted?

i.e. Is the Session kept open long enough for Hibernate to know that the domain objects which populated the UI are now "dirty" and should be updated?

I thought it (OpenSessionInViewFilter) was only used to keep the hibernate session open long enough to allow the Web/UI layer to access lazy loaded collections etc and then it closed.

Answer (score 0):

> i.e. Is the Session kept open long enough for Hibernate to know that
>   the domain objects which populated the UI are now "dirty" and should
>   be updated?

In theory, yes. However: Database Objects should never change in the web layer! If they do, you have your layers mixed up.

Comment: So. Say we pulled a User from the db using hibernate, sent that User object to UI (with OpenSessionInViewFilter enabled). The User was then updated via UI. Hibernate would update the User on submit?